# Java Web MVC Update

Tags: java, model-view-controller, crud

I am learning Java CRUD Operation. I am trying to update records from sql database.The insert and displaying all records methods is working but the problem is when I click update nothing happens.

Here is my modal HTML for Update.

```
            <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
                      .modal-content  {
                         width: 20%;
                         text-align: center;
                        }
                    </style>
                        <span class="close">×</span>
                        <h2 style="text-align: center";>Modificar un beneficio</h2>
                        <form action="MantenedorBeneficios" method="get" var="reg" items="${lista_beneficios}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="cargar"/>
                            <label>Nombre Beneficio: </label>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_beneficio" value="${reg.getId()}"/>
                            <input type="text" name="nombreBe" value="${reg.getnombre()}" />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" > Modificar Beneficio </button>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the Data Access code for CRUD operation.

```
 public static List<RegistroMantenedorBeneficios> cargarBeneficio(){
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    List<RegistroMantenedorBeneficios> lista_registros = new ArrayList<RegistroMantenedorBeneficios>();
    RegistroMantenedorBeneficios registro = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    
    try{
        conn = c.Conectar();
        Statement stm = conn.prepareStatement("Select from * beneficio where id_beneficio=?");
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();                                      
          while (rs.next()) {
            registro = new RegistroMantenedorBeneficios();
            registro.id = rs.getInt("id");
            registro.nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
            registro.id_tipo = rs.getInt("id_tipo_beneficio");
            registro.vigente = rs.getBoolean("vigente");
            lista_registros.add(registro);
         
          }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        System.out.println(">>> Exception BeneficiosDB/InsertarNuevoBeneficio \n" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        c.cerrarConexion(conn);
    }
    return lista_registros;
 }
```

Here is the servlet code .

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    String accion = request.getParameter("accion");
    
    if (accion != null && accion.equals("vigencia")){
        int id_ben = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        boolean is_vig = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("bool"));
        
        BeneficiosDB.ActualizarVigenciaBeneficio(id_ben, is_vig);
    }
    
    if (accion != null && accion.equals("insertar")){
        String nombre = request.getParameter("nombreBe");
        int id_tipo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id_tipo"));
        int vigente = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("bool"));
        
        BeneficiosDB.InsertarNuevoBeneficio(nombre, id_tipo, vigente);
    }
    //not working
        if (accion != null && accion.equals("cargar")){
            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id_beneficio"));
            String nombre = request.getParameter("nombreBe");
            int id_tipo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id_tipo"));
            boolean vigente = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("vigente"));
        
    }

    
    List<RegistroMantenedorBeneficios> registros_beneficios = BeneficiosDB.ListaBeneficios();
    //List<RegistroMantenedorBeneficios> registros_beneficioss = BeneficiosDB.cargarBeneficio();
    //request.setAttribute("lista_beneficioss", registros_beneficioss);
    request.setAttribute("lista_beneficios", registros_beneficios);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Mantenedores/MantenedorBeneficios.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood you question right you are trying to update a record from modal where id is "id_beneficio" and since there is only one visible field I assume it is suppose to update value of "nombreBe".

with these assumptions there are couple of things you need to correct

1. BeneficiosDB.cargarBeneficio is should be called from you controller before BeneficiosDB.ListaBeneficios.
2. Your sql is a normal select stmt it needs to be update stmt and also
   you need to set the value of id_beneficio and nombreBe in stmt using
   your sql should be

```
 update beneficio set nombreBe = ? where where id_beneficio=?
 stmt.setInt(nombreBe); // can be setString depending on your data-type.
 stmt.setInt(id_beneficio);
```

Please verify the update query once before using it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer I will try your suggestion. What I'm trying to do is, first to display all data that contain id_beneficio in the modal form and then create a button to update de data

Comment: got it @Lambda that explains BeneficiosDB.ListaBeneficios call